# reg_write64 MMIO register error in rocket chip

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

I am trying to write a 64 bit word to the MMIO register using the `reg_write64`
construct defined in `mmio.h`. Everything works fine as long as the wire that I map this register to in chisel land is not decoupled. As soon as I make this wire decoupled the execution hangs and does not complete. For example, this is my Chisel code

```
val wireToConnect = Wire(Decoupled(Bits(64.W))) //This  works when I don't have decoupled
regmap(
0x00 -> Seq(RegField.w(64, wireToConnect))))
```

And this is my C code for writing into this register

```
#include "mmio.h"
#define WRITEVAL 0x2000
int main(void){
    uint64_t data = 123456;
    reg_write64(WRITEVAL, data);
}
```

However when I replace reg_write64 with reg_write32 this works. Is there any particular setting which we need to set to make sure that decoupled interfaces can work with 64 bit wide registers?

Comment: What is the diplomacy node `beatBytes`? If you set it to 8 does it work?

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the bit width. Since it is already 64 bits, a decoupled is going to add a ready and valid bit to this interface which exceeds the bitwidth allowed by registers. We get an error that regmap is overlapping if we have more than 64 bits. I don't know how to by pass this though. If anyone knows please let me know.